# ATG 10.2 -MessageBrokerServlet is currently unavailable error

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

I am trying  to setup a new ATG site. while accessing the Site Administration-->Site assets 
from the ATG bussiness control center, it generating a popup

```
Unable to connect to the server at http://localhost:8180/FlexUI/messagebroker/amf
```

While checking the server error logs and cmd, It showing

`[[MessageBrokerServlet]] Servlet MessageBrokerServlet is currently unavailable.`

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your cookies and login again. I sometimes get that error when my session has expired, but the Flex interface is not aware of it.

If the problem persists, take a look at your logs, and see if there were any errors during the BCC startup. If so, post them here so I can try and help you.

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you running. I am hoping JBOSS, if yes. Go to your BCC server under jboss. And In its deploy folder check for

FlexUI.war > WEB-INF > web.xml

by the end of the file you will find

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>flex.messaging.MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MessageBrokerServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/messagebroker/*</url-pattern>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Remove `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` and restart your BCC. The error should go away.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Removing the MessageBrokerServlet load-on-startup works

Comment: Please add more to your "answer"